# Deploying couchbase in a docker swarm environment

Tags: docker, couchbase, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I'm trying to deploy couchbase community edition in  a docker swarm environment.  I followed the steps suggested [by Arun Gupta](https://github.com/arun-gupta/docker-images/tree/master/couchbase), though I'm not sure if a master-worker model is desired as Couchbase doesn't have the notion of master/slave model.

Following are the problems I encountered.  I'm wondering if anyone is able to run Couchbase successfully in a swarm mode.

- Docker swarm assigns different IP address each time the service is restarted.  Sometimes, docker moves the service to a new node which, again assigns a different IP address.  It appears [that Couchbase doesn't start](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-3-0-2-changing-ip-address-of-server/5699) if it finds a new IP address.  (log says `"address on which the service is configured is not up.  Waiting for the interface to be brought up"`).  I'm using a host mounted volume as the data folder (`/opt/couchase/var`) to persist data across restarts.
- I tried to read overlay network address used internally and update `ip` and `ip_start` files in a `run` script within the container.  This doesn't help either.  Server comes up as a new instance without loading old data.  This is a real problem as production data can be lost if `docker swarm` moves services around.
- `docker swarm's` internal router assigns an address from overlay network in addition to other interfaces.  I tried using `localhost`, `master.overlaynet`, IP address of the overlaynet, private address assigned by docker to container  etc. as server address in the Couchbase cluster configuration.  While the cluster servers are able to communicate to each other, this created another problem with client connections.  Client normally connects to an address/port exposed by the swarm cluster.  This is different from cluster node address. In case of a python client, it reads Couchbase cluster server addresses and tried to connect to that if overlay address is given as server address at the time of joining the cluster.  The client times out as the address is not reachable.
- I might be able to add a network address constraint to the `yaml` file to ensure that master node will come up with the same address.  For eg.

```
    networks:
        default:
           ipv4_address: 172.20.x.xx
```

- Above approach may not work for worker nodes as that will impact ability to scale worker nodes based on load/growth.
- In this model (master/worker), how does a worker get elected as leader if master node goes down?  Is master/worker the right approach for a Couchbase cluster in swarm environment?

It will be helpful if I can get some references to Couchbase swarm mode setup or some suggestions on how to handle IP address change.

Answer (score 3):

We ran into the same problem (couchbase server 5.1.1) and our temporary solution is to use fixed IPs on a new docker bridge network.

```
networks:<br>
    default:<br>
        ipv4_address: 172.19.0.x
```

Although this works, this is not a good solution as we loose auto-scaling as mentioned above. We had some learnings during setup. Just to let you know:

1. You can run a single-node couchbase setup with dynamic IP. You can stop/restart this container and update couchbase-server version with no limitations.
2. When you add a second node this initially works with dynamic IP as well during setup. You can add the server and rebalance the cluster. But when you stop/restart/scale 0/1 a couchbase container, it won't start up anymore due to a new IP provides by docker (10.0.0.x with default network).
3. Changing the "ip" or "ip_start" files (/opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/config) to update the IP does NOT work. Server starts up as "new" server, when changing the ip in "ip" and "ip_start" but it still has all the data. So you can backup your data, if you need now. So even after you "switched" to fixed IP you can't re-start the server directly, but need to cbbackup and cbrestore.
4. https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.1/install/hostnames.html documentation for using hostnames is a little misleading as this only documents how to "find" a new server while configuring a cluster. If you specify hostnames couchbase anyway configures all nodes with the static IPs.
5. You might start your docker swarm with host network might be a solution, but we run multiple instances of other containers on a single host, so we would like to avoid that solution.

So always have a backup of the node/cluster. We always make a file-backup and a cluster-backup with cbbackup. As restoring from a file backup is much faster.

There is a discussion at https://github.com/couchbase/docker/issues/82 on this issue, but this involves using AWS for static IPs, which we don't.

I am aware of couchbase autonomous operator for kubernetes, but for now we would like to stay with docker swarm. If anybody has a nicer solution for this, how to configure couchbase to use hostnames, please share.

Comment: Thank you for the update.  My experience with Couchbase in docker swarm is same as above.  I've been trying to associate a static IP from the overlay network as that's needed for other services to connect.  Looks like that's not allowed either.  I'll try your suggestion of static IP  from bridge network.

Comment: We now got it running by thf following approach, where you at least keep scaling for most containers:

1. Remove all couchbase containers from your stack deploy file. Leave all other containers in there.

2. Create an attachable overlay network:

3. start couchbase with docker run outside of docker stack deploy with the overlay network and --ip=172.9.0.x (for example)

4. start the stack

This works for us